# docker-compose not running commands

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

I have such docker-compose:

```
web:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: environments/production/Dockerfile
  links:
      - fpm:fpm
      - redis:redis
      - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
      - beanstalkd:beanstalkd
  volumes:
      - /var/cache/nginx
      - ../../:/app:ro
...
composer:
  image: imega/composer
  volumes:
    - ../../:/data
  command: ["install"]
node:
  image: node:slim
  volumes:
    - ../../:/app
  working_dir: /app
  entrypoint: npm
  command: ["install"]
```

The goal is to install composer and node deps on build. And it should work theoretically, but in fact command written in containers definition doesn't executing. Any command. I've tried to run 'echo' there, or 'ls .' — nothing.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding a couple things here:

- You are running `npm install` to install dependencies in a volume and then the volume is consumed by your application container. This isn't containing any dependencies in the application image. While this might work, it means that image doesn't really run on its own. When you ship this image to production, you are breaking a contract that says "this application is the same as development". Be aware of this.
- You are running `npm install` as a service which will eventually exit. When the command exits, the container stops. More over, the `web` service (which likely depends on these dependencies) may start before the `npm install` has finished.

Is there a reason you don't want to have `composer install` and `npm install` as part of your application build process?

Comment: Volume is set to host directory and this is the idea — service interacts with host directly and installs dependencies directly to host. And this is how this containers are designed to use: https://hub.docker.com/r/imega/composer/

Problem is not in certain services, but with that ANY command passed to "command" don't work. I write there 'ls .' or 'echo hi' — no output.

»» Is there a reason you don't want to have composer install and npm install as part of your application build process?
— in fact I'm trying to get optimal workflow for autodeployments. You think there is a better approach?

Comment: Earlier I've tried an approach when application builds and tests in main container (web) and this all is written in dockerfile. That was working, but now I try to make things more dry, more single responsible as it should be in docker. I've even separated nginx from fpm. And with this in mind I'm trying to rework the workflow..

Answer (score 0):

don't use command: ["install"]

to try:

command: install